# Java - How can I use a 3 argument constructor to set 2 instance variables

Tags: java, constructor, uml, diagram

I'm new to java and I have to use a 3 argument `Circle()` constructor to set 2 instance variables `radius` and `center` . I have to use `x` and `y` for the `center`. Bellow is the UML diagram I'm working with. Thanks in advance.
[image]

```
public class Circle extends Point
{
  private double radius;
  private Point center;

  public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
  {
    super(x, y);
    this.radius = radius;
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe a beginners Java tutorial might be a good place to start if you're stuck straight away.

Comment: I tried to use `extend` for the class and `super` in the constructor but I'm not sure it's the right method.

Comment: What are you extending? Maybe include a [mre] in your question,

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: If a Circle *is a* Point, why are you adding a Point as a field in the Circle class?

Comment: Post your clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: The question you have to ask here is: do you consider a circle to be a point? If it inherits from it, it should be able to be defined as one, in the same way that a dog is an animal or a mango is a fruit. A circle *has* a point (its center), but I wouldn't say it is one. Try removing the inheritance and considering setting `center` to something in the `Circle` constructor. Regardless, you should probably follow some tutorials on OOP, it will be much more useful for you than asking here.

Comment: You have not yet asked a specific narrowly-focused question.

Comment: Sorry but it's getting a bit confusing for me. This is an exercise from my university thus the diagram was made by them.

Comment: In that case I would definitely do your research first, some basic OOP concepts, maybe what a UML diagram is if you don't understand it, etc. It would be disingenuous to do your university exercises for you here.

Comment: Why do you consider this to be disingenuous? Every method is good as long as I benefit from it. I would better ask more question than just sit and do nothing to improve myself.

Comment: Someone completing your assignment for you. You doing it yourself would be much better for your education (and I am sure that was your universities intention with the exercise). There's good detail [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) about asking homework-style questions.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks for the response, I will definitely do more research in the future.

Answer (score 1):

That diagram indicates that the relationship between `Circle` and `Point` is a Composition.

So the relevant java code is:

```
public class Circle
{
  private double radius;
  private Point center;

  public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
  {
    this.radius = radius;
    center = new Point(x, y);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. The constructor should be like this:

```
 public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
  {
    center = new Point(x, y);
    this.radius = radius;
  }
```